# How to read files from remote Server?

Tags: php, server

I am currently programming a Control Panel for Minecraft Servers, and want now to know, how do I read for example a Configuration file, which is located on a remote server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use `fopen()` to read from remote server:

```
fopen('http://www.google.com/', 'r');
```

For more details check [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php). 
Some other methods to read files from remote server are [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php) and [cURL](http://php.net/manual/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 0):

I am using now a class (http://php.net/manual/de/function.ssh2-sftp.php) which is actually doing everything i want

Answer (score -1):

use file_get_contents

```
$file = file_get_contents("path_to_file");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($file);
```

Comment: Why do you post solution that has been already posted by other user?

Comment: this method was not in any answer

Comment: he update his answer that was not there when i wrote this answer